# Ubuntu Clamscan help

Tags: clamav

I ran `sudo clamscan -i -r -v --remove=yes /` and got a lot of known viruses, but I do not know how to delete them. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: What are you scanning ? Linux does not have any significant known active viruses and you have to be very very careful as clam av gives false positives.

Comment: What part of "infected files:  0" do you not understand ?

Answer (score 1):

You really should understand commands before you run them.

```
man clamscan
```

> --remove[=yes/no(*)]
>
> Remove infected files. Be careful!

So the command you ran should have removed the "infected" files.

BE CAREFUL CLAMAV IS NOTORIOUS FOR FALSE POSITIVES. I HIGHLY SUGGEST YOU REVIEW THE FILES BEFORE YOU REMOVE THEM.

I HIGHLY ADVISE YOU USE THE `--move` option.

```
--move=INFECTED
```

or any directory you wish.

Also , clamav will not remove files if you do not have permission to do so, so you may need to run it as root.

```
sudo clamscan -i --move=INFECTED
```